# Close Lean Modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to close the lean modal programaticaly after ajax call.But it's not working.

```
$("form#loginform").submit(function (event) {
            $('.regerrormsg').text('');
            $('.loginerrormsg').text('');
            $('.loginbtn').val('Processing...');
            $(".loginbtn").prop('disabled', true);
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./LoginProcess.php",
                data: $('#loginform').serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response === 'ok') {
                        $('#loginform').each(function () {
                            this.reset();
                        });
                        $('.loginsuccessmsg').text('Loggedin successfully....');
                        $('.loginsuccessmsg').fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
                        $('.loginbtn').val('Register');
                        $(".loginbtn").prop('disabled', false);
                        function redirectreg() {
                            $("#lean_overlay").trigger("click");
                        }
                        setTimeout(redirectreg, 5000);
                    } else {
                        $('.loginerrormsg').text(response);
                        $('.loginbtn').val('Register');
                        $(".loginbtn").prop('disabled', false);
                        $('.loginerrormsg').fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I tried with $("#lean_overlay").trigger("click");.This also not working.Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $("#lean_overlay").trigger("click");
    $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(); //with animation
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.